# enum compareTo operator overloading with nullable value

Tags: kotlin

I have an enum `SupportUsLevel` defined in Kotlin. Its raw type is a string (for other reasons), but I have included a `numeric` value as an `Int` to facilitate comparison. I want to compare this enum to another enum but this one can also be null. So I implemented a compareTo operator that takes an nullable `other`:

```
enum class SupportUsLevel(val value: String) {

    red("red"),
    blue("blue"),
    black("black");

    val numeric: Int
        get() {
            when (this) {
                red -> return 1
                blue -> return 5
                black -> return 7
            }
        }

    //return 0 if equal, negative (-1) is smaller, positive(+1) is bigger
    operator fun SupportUsLevel.compareTo(other: SupportUsLevel?) : Int {
        //if other is null, since I cannot be null, I am always bigger
        if (other == null) {
            return 1
        }
        //return numeric comparison since we both now have a value (due to null-check before)
        return numeric.compareTo(other.numeric)
       }
}
```

However when I want to use it, it seams that this custom comparTo is not being recognised by the compiler? I get a type mismatch:

[image]

Comment: Enums have an intrinsic natural ordering which is the ordering of thei ordinal, i.e. the order in which they are declared. You can't override that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo-E-

Comment: but the ordinal is a string? Or do you mean the order in which they ware declared? So overloading an operator to compare to a nullable not possible?

Comment: The ordinal is the position of the enum constant in the declarations. 0 for red, 1 for blue, 2 for black. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--

Comment: right, thanks for the info. But implementing a custom compareTo that takes a nullable is thus just not possible?

Comment: An instance method is always preferred over an extension function.

Comment: Thats a shame (not so in Swift that is one advantage then for it), I will just make it a std member function

Answer (score 0):

An instance methode is always preferred over an extension (see comments of JB Nizet in the org question), this means that the custom defined compareTo is never being recognised by the compiler.

Best solution I could find is to make it a standard member function
(note its not a compare anymore but a `isHigherThen`(...) since that is what I needed):

```
enum class SupportUsLevel(val value: String) {

    //since we are using the standard enum compare operator the order must be low to high!
    //refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456649/enum-compareto-operator-overloading-with-nullable-value

    red("red"),
    blue("blue"),
    black("black");

    val numeric: Int
        get() {
            when (this) {
                red -> return 1
                blue -> return 5
                black -> return 7
            }
        }

    fun isHigherThen(other: SupportUsLevel?) : Boolean {
        //if other is null, since I cannot be null, I am always bigger
        if (other == null) { return true }
        //return numeric comparison since we both now have a value (due to null-check before)
        return numeric > other.numeric
    }
}
```